# Commercial Use of QGIS

Tags: qgis, license

Can QGIS be used for commercial purposes? In particular, the output of maps/pictures for commercial use in reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS is published under the "GNU General Public License" (source: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/about/index.html), so yes, it can be used for commercial purposes (see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License).

But it really took me a Google search to find that on the QGIS site, after some unsuccessful browsing.

Comment: It is you who owns the copyright for the maps and images that you create with QGIS. GPL does not stick to the produced works, it affects development of software that is utilizing QGIS code.

Comment: @user30184 unfortunately it is not that simple. You also need to be aware of the underlying data which has its own copyright reglementations in most cases.

Comment: Good point. However, QGIS does not add anything to that.