# Is installing QGIS on company computer legal?

Tags: qgis, license

I would like to ask if a company computer install QGIS software is legal or not. One of my colleague require to install that software. IT division will install only a legal software for user and ask me to check if it's legal or not. Or could you please provide me the legal way to install that?

https://qgis.org/zh-Hant/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: See here on the official site : https://qgis.org/zh-Hant/site/about/index.html (> `QGIS 是建立於(且榮幸成為)自由和開源軟體(FOSS)之上的專業 GIS 應用程式。`).

Comment: What is "legal" in one country might not be "legal" in another. Where are you? What do you even mean by "legal software"? What laws might the software be breaking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commercial Use of QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364371/commercial-use-of-qgis)

Answer (score 9):

I am not a lawyer but, according to the information that you provide, it is legal to install QGIS on a computer of your company.

QGIS is distributed under [GPL licence, version 2](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/GNU_GPL.html). Basically, it guarantees you freedom to run, study, share, and modify the software. The legal constraint is that, if your company wants to distribute a modified copy of the software, it has to be done under the same or equivalent license terms (GPL is a copyleft licence, see [here](https://dwheeler.com/essays/floss-license-slide.html) some compatibility examples). But if you run the software for your own purpose, there is no condition on what you produce with the software (data, maps, statistics produced by the software are your property, and you can decide how to distribute it (or not to distribute it)).

You can read the full GPL licence if you need more details.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License

DISCLAIMER: As mentioned in the comment, there are some cases where installing a software on a computer could be illegal (e.g. if the owner of the computer does not give his consent), so only a lawyer of your country could be sure that what you do is legal. My understanding of the question is: could QGIS.org file suit to someone who installs and uses QGIS on a computer? And the answer to this question is "no".

Comment: Careful with giving legal advice. There may be instances where installing QGIS may be an illegal act, for example if you don't own the computer in question. There's a reason why people say "this does not constitute legal advice, I am not a lawyer" on the internet.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Comment: @Spacedman - I'm not a lawyer, either. But in my understanding, in your case not QGIS (or it's license) is the problem, but the fact that you act in ANY way on someone else's computer. The simple act of accessing the machine constitutes an illegal action. If you install QGIS or not on this machine does not make any difference: it does no (further) harm to anyone. You already acted illegally before you got the chance to install any software.

Comment: I think the question is more about user rights in a company setting. There are cases where end-users are restricted in what they are allowed to install on the computers in the company that hires them. Security, stability etc. might play a role here. So it might be not strictly illegal (in the sense of violating state laws), but still be banned by internal, company-made rules. So good advice would be to ask the owner of the computer (and/or the IT department) about what you're allowed to do on the machine. But as stressed otherwise: from the side of QGIS developers, you're free to install it.